# What causes this error with a Groovy Closure?

Tags: groovy, closures

```
a = {
    b = {
        println 'b'
    }
    println 'c'
}

a().b()
```

The code above will cause an error:

[image: error like this]

But after removing `println 'c'` , `a().b()` will print 'b' with no error.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Please post code and error message as text, not as images. That allows them to be more easily read and searched for.

Comment: I don't think your code is doing what you think it is See `a().a().a().a()`

Answer (score 1):

Without the print statement, `b` was implicitly returned by `a`'s closure. Adding the `println` causes null (`println()` is a `void` method) to be implicitly returned instead.

If you modify your closure like so, it will work as expected:

```
a = {
    b = {
        println 'b'
    }
    println 'c'
    return b
}
```

Writing `return` is optional in Groovy; the last line of a method or closure is automatically returned.